# jQuery .on('load') doesn't work with an object/iframe while .addEventListener('load') does

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to modify an iframe/object content adding a script into it. At the moment, I have something like this:

```
// "script" is a node with an self-called function as its content
$(function() {
    $('object, iframe').each(function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            this.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script.cloneNode(true));
        });
    });
});
```

And it works as expected (the script does its job and it is added to the DOM of the iframe) but the problem comes when I try to do it the "jQuery" way:

```
// "script" is a node with an self-called function as its content
$(function() {
    $('object, iframe').each(function() {
        $(this).on('load', function() {
            this.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script.cloneNode(true));
        });
    });
});
```

In the previous code, the script won't be added to the dom of the iframe.

Is there any reason why the `.on('load')` version is not working? What can be wrong? Am I missing something?

PS: The iframe is same-origin.

Comment: Have you jQuery in iframe?

Comment: Should be equivalent

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the jquery way?

Comment: @yellowmint I do have jQuery in the iframe.

Comment: @SED The script is not being added to the DOM. I can also replace the line where I add the scripts with an 'alert('hi')` and I would get a "hi" in the first example but not in the second one.

Comment: Compare what `this` is in each scenario. If it works in one and not the other, i'd expect that to be the difference.

Comment: @KevinB I used the debugger and I got that both `this` are the same object, but the event is never fired in the .addEventListener version. https://i.imgbox.com/Fntn2c2J.png https://i.imgbox.com/29Pgronr.png

Comment: It might be helpful if you created a https://jsfiddle.net/ and linked to it that includes the html as well so it is easier to run/test and you might even find the answer on accident by going through the motions of setting it up for us to help you

Answer (score -1):

In each case, the inner function's `this` might not always be what you want it to be. I'd try:

```
$(function() {
    $('object, iframe').each(function () {
        $(this).on('load', function (event) {
            event.target.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script.cloneNode(true));
        });
    });
});
```

Cf. https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem as the .addEventListener version is the one that is working. The problem comes with .on('load') that should be equivalent, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing changed. I've tried to recreate what's happening in simple HTML pages and both the codes I shared seem to work, so it must be something else. Any ideas?